# Uncaught TypeError Object has not method 'disable'

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my previous version of the application, this code worked fine:

```
form.find('input').disable();
```

With new environment (Rails 3.3 and new version of JQuery) this doesn't work anymore.

The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError Object[object Object] has not method 'disable'.

Why do I get this error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[].forEach.call( form.elements, function ( el ) { el.disabled = true } )
```

or in jQuery maybe...

```
$(document.forms['form_name'].elements).each(function() {
   this.disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: +1 for the only sensible answer... but you know he'll want a jQuery solution as well.

Comment: yea but I always see the dumbest jQuery answers... like if you're going to use the library you should at least use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `disable()` but `prop("disabled", true)` instead.

As far as I know, there never was `disable()` method in jQuery

Comment: The second argument (that is, the value) should probably just be `true`, since the DOM property is a boolean and not a string. (The string form is appropriate for the *attribute*, but not the *property*, in other words.) The string will work however because, when coerced to boolean, it's `true`.

Comment: No @Xander you're incorrect. Look at the DOM spec: the **property** is a boolean, not a string. In the HTML markup, you set the **attribute** to "disabled", but the **property** of the DOM element is a boolean. (Ooops Xander deleted his comment :-)

Comment: @pointy yeah, you're right. it is different than using `.attr`

Comment: @Xander right. It doesn't *really* matter, however, because the non-empty string "disabled" is just as `true` as `true` :-)  Stackoverflow is the place where we get to be needlessly pedantic however!

Comment: why do I need jQuery to set element properties???? `.` all of a sudden got too hard to write? (just making a point) `form.disabled = true;` **disclaimer: I don't think you can disable an entire form like this**